# Remove from arraylist by value

Tags: java, arraylist

I implement the `equals()` to be able to remove an array list elements by value:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Character)) return false;
    Character ch = (Character) obj;
    return ch.equals(this);
}
```

And this is my arraylist:

```
static ArrayList<Character> sr = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

contains:

```
Sr: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

I'm going to remove `a` and `b` characters:

```
public static removeChars(){

    ...
    sr.remove('a');
    sr.remove('b');

}
```

But always two last items (`g` and `f`) had been deleted.

Comment: Is `Character` a custom class you've written (or is it `java.lang.Character`?). Which class contains the `equals` method you posted?

Comment: @MickMnemonic it looks like it's being autoboxed in the call to `remove` so that means it must be `java.lang.Character` right? Though I'm not sure why OP is implementing a custom `equals` in that case.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case in `removeChars`, which makes me wonder where the `equals` implementation resides. Seems that lots of relevant code has been omitted from the question.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I'm guessing it's a custom Character and OP doesn't realise how autoboxing works. I've answered on that assumption.

Comment: @MickMnemonic No, it's not custom class,  `Character` is `java.lang.Character`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `java.lang.Character` in your `ArrayList` then you shouldn't need to implement `equals`. If it is your own `Character` then the call to `remove` is not creating objects of your class - it's creating standard `Character` objects which is why they don't `equal` the items in the list.

If this is the problem then you need to ensure you pass instances of your class to the call to `remove` rather than relying on [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html):

```
sr.remove(new Character('a'));
```

Alternatively if you are using Java 8 you could explicitly implement an `equalsChar` method and call it in a predicate:

```
sr.removeIf(c -> c.equalsChar('a'));
```

This has the advantage of removing all instances (not just the first one) which is often what is required for a `List` rather than a `Set`.